# Why am I getting a 400 response with a type error for my GraphQL query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I've tried looking elsewhere for a fix/answer as to where I'm going wrong, but I've had no luck.

When trying to call my `getPostsByUser` query in my React frontend, I get a `400` response, with the error of `Variable \"$userId\" of required type \"ID!\" was not provided.`

I've checked my types, and I think everything seems to be in order, and when debugging I can see that the 'correct' `userId` is being passed, but still I'm not having any luck.

Thanks in advance!

**Query hook:**

```
const GET_POSTS_BY_USER_QUERY = gql`
  query getPostsByUser($userId: ID!) {
    getPostsByUser(userId: $userId) {
      title
      subtitle
      difficulty
      body
      commentCount
      comments {
        body
        createdAt
        id
        username
      }
      createdAt
      id
      likeCount
      likes {
        createdAt
        id
        username
      }
      username
      user
    }
  }
`;

export const useGetPostsByUser = (userId) => {
  const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(GET_POSTS_BY_USER_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      userId,
    },
  });

  return { loading, data, error };
};
```

**Called in the UI as:**

```
const { loadingPosts, data = {}, error } = useGetPostsByUser(userId);
```

Again, where the `userId` being passed is correct.

**Query type:**

```
  type Post {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    subtitle: String!
    body: String!
    createdAt: String!
    username: String!
    user: ID!
    comments: [Comment]!
    commentCount: Int!
    likes: [Like]!
    likeCount: Int!
    difficulty: String!
  }

  type Query {
    getPostsByUser(userId: ID!): [Post]
  }
```

**Post schema:**

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  subtitle: String,
  body: String,
  username: String,
  createdAt: String,
  comments: [
    {
      body: String,
      username: String,
      createdAt: String,
    },
  ],
  likes: [
    {
      username: String,
      createdAt: String,
    },
  ],
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  difficulty: String,
});
```

**Query resolver:**

```
    getPostsByUser: async (_, { userId }) => {
      try {
        const posts = await Post.find();
        const postsByUser = (posts || []).filter(
          (post) => post.user === userId
        );

        if (postsByUser) {
          return postsByUser;
        } else {
          return 'No posts by this User were found';
        }
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    },
```

Additionally, `postsByUser` returns an empty array, whereas `posts` returns an array of 27 entries (of multiple users.

Any help is hugely appreciated - I've been stuck on this for days! Thanks everyone <3 I'm happy to provide any other information if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it...

I moved the query call in the UI *down* a component - I think the call was being made before the `userId` could be fetched - and I changed the query resolver in the GraphQL to:

```
    getPostsByUser: async (_, { userId }) => {
      try {
        const posts = await Post.find({ user: userId });
        return posts;
      } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    },
```

Seems to be doing the trick!